# React - propTypes for parent component rendering a library?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have  question:
I am using `react-dates datepicker` library and I wonder: I cant define propTypes (as where I render the `datepicker` I dont use any props) but what is considered good react practise in a case like that? When I don't use a library but write my hild component myself, I will defined the proptypes inside the child myself etc. but what is when Im using a library where 'their code' is not as easy to look up? I my case (please see code below) its for example mandatory that the property "startDate" is an object. Would it be good when I somehow define it insight my component so others can easily see what is expected? 
I am just trying to write better code and wonder what would be best in a case like that. Thanks!!

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
   render(){
      return (
         <DayPickerRangeController
            startDate={this.state.startDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
            endDate={this.state.endDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
            onDatesChange={({ startDate, endDate }) => this.setState({ startDate, endDate })} // PropTypes.func.isRequired,
            focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput} // PropTypes.oneOf([START_DATE, END_DATE]) or null,
            onFocusChange={focusedInput => this.setState({ focusedInput })} // PropTypes.func.isRequired,
         />
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: Its better if you write it inside of the component `DayPickerRangeController ` where u defining ir

Comment: I am not defining DayPickerRangeController, thats the reason for my question- what to do if Im not defining it-just using it since its a library

Answer (score 1):

You can define a wrapper functional component which delegates all props to the child component and associate prop types with that.

```
export const DayPickerWrapper = (props) => <DayPickerRangeController {...props}/>;

DayPickerWrapper.propTypes = { /* Add additional validations here */ }
```

In the rest of your application, you can use DayPickerWrapper instead of DayPicker.

---

If you really want to avoid the overhead of a wrapper, you can also directly change the propTypes of the component class:

```
DayPickerRangeController.propTypes = {
  ...DayPickerRangeController.propTypes,
  // Add custom validations here
}
```

And import it once before using it in render.